# How to disable quarantine completely in macOS?

Tags: macos, macos-bigsur, quarantine

In macOS Big Sur (v11.2.3), how can I completely disable the following warning (see screenshot), for all applications I ever download? Yes, I know of the potential security risks, and I'm willing to take them.

I've tried:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
```

And I've also completely disabled Gatekeeper:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

I tried rebooting my system, but still, macOS keeps adding the quarantine flag to any new files I download (I'm not concerned about old ones I've already downloaded). What else can I try?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As a workaround, you might consider attaching a folder action script to your downloads folder which automatically strips off the quarantine attribute from any file that appears in that folder.

Comment: @Spiff - Thank you for the suggestion! See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do this natively. But as @Spiff recommended in the comment above, there is a workaround:

First, install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), if you haven't already. Then, run the following three commands in your Terminal:

```
brew install watchman
watchman watch ~/Downloads
watchman -- trigger ~/Downloads removequarantine '*' -- ~/remove-quarantine.sh
```

The first command will install [watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman), an open-source file watching tool.
The other two commands will set up a watcher for the Downloads folder. Anytime a file is added or modified in that folder, watchman will call the script in `~/remove-quarantine.sh`. We still have to create that script. Using a text editor, create a new file and name it `remove-quarantine.sh`, place it in your home folder, and add the following line to it:

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads/$1
```

You can find more details in a [blog post](https://hiringengineersbook.com/post/disable-quarantine/) I made about this.